# Python/Ansible - Unsupported parameters for module

Tags: python, ansible

All,
I Found a useful collection (git repo link below) for my ansible playbook which simplifies the way mongo atlas database users are created. The collection houses a set of Python modules and only support the creation of database user names with passwords. What I have been trying to do is to update the script slightly such that I could add create user AD authenticated user groups and as such had modified the script to add the extra "ldapAuthType" parameter to the atlas_user.py module.

https://github.com/T-Systems-MMS/ansible-collection-mongodb-atlas

However, when I run the ansible task, it fails with

`fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (user) module: ldapAuthType Supported parameters include: apiPassword, apiUsername, databaseName, groupId, password roles, state, username"}`

To illustrate, I have the example ansible task snippet below also given in the atlas_user.py module
https://github.com/T-Systems-MMS/ansible-collection-mongodb-atlas/blob/master/plugins/modules/atlas_user.py#L93

```
- name: test user
      atlas_user:
        apiUsername: "API_user"
        apiPassword: "API_passwort_or_token"
        groupId: "GROUP_ID"
        username: my_app_user
        password: SuperSecret!
        roles:
          - databaseName: private_info
            roleName: read
          - databaseName: public_info
            roleName: readWrite
```

What I what to achieve is a task that has the ldapAuthType as a parameter as shown below. For this auth type I don't need the password parameter so have excluded it.

```
- name: atlas user
  atlas_user:
    apiUsername: "efewfwefef"
    apiPassword: "efwef-wefwefwefwef-ewfwefwefwe-ewe"
    groupId: "3241efdva2q4tqvaegq3488888"
    databaseName: "admin"
    ldapAuthType: "GROUP"
    username: "CN=bro-grp,OU=ComDB,OU=Srv accts,OU=Cloud Atlas,DC=Com,DC=net"
    roles:
      - databaseName: mydb
        roleName: readWrite
      - databaseName: somedb
        roleName: read
```

I have been trying to add the ldapAuthType parameter in the atlas_user.py module but I get the error mentioned above when I run the ansible task. I'm a python novice so any help is appreciated.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

__metaclass__ = type

ANSIBLE_METADATA = {
    "metadata_version": "0.1",
    "status": ["preview"],
    "supported_by": "community",
}


from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule
from ansible_collections.t_systems_mms.mongodb_atlas.plugins.module_utils.atlas import (
    AtlasAPIObject,
)


# ===========================================
# Module execution.
#
def main():
    # add our own arguments
    argument_spec = dict(
        state=dict(default="present", choices=["absent", "present"]),
        apiUsername=dict(required=True),
        apiPassword=dict(required=True, no_log=True),
        groupId=dict(required=True),
        databaseName=dict(default="admin", choices=["admin", "$external"]),
 ==>>>  ldapAuthType=dict(default="GROUP", choices=["GROUP","USER"]),  
        username=dict(required=True),
        password=dict(required=False, no_log=True),
        roles=dict(
            required=True,
            type="list",
            options=dict(
                databaseName=dict(required=True), roleName=dict(required=True),
            ),
        ),
    )

    # Define the main module
    module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec=argument_spec, supports_check_mode=True
    )

    data = {
        "databaseName": module.params["databaseName"],
 ==>>>  "ldapAuthType": module.params["ldapAuthType"],
        "username": module.params["username"],
        "password": module.params["password"],
        "roles": module.params["roles"],
    }

    try:
        atlas = AtlasAPIObject(
            module=module,
            path="/databaseUsers",
            object_name="username",
            groupId=module.params["groupId"],
            data=data,
        )
    except Exception as e:
        module.fail_json(
            msg="unable to connect to Atlas API. Exception message: %s" % e
        )

    changed, diff = atlas.update(module.params["state"])
    module.exit_json(
        changed=changed, data=atlas.data, diff=diff,
    )


# import module snippets
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You have included some python, but not how that relates to your question -- what file is that python contained in, and you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65397524/edit) to include the playbook task that is causing the error output. No one can **guess** your specifics

Comment: @mdaniel - Question edited to bring the whole thing into context, hopefully it should be sufficient

Comment: Thank you for the updated snippets. However, you omitted where that python code lives on disk, since if you just put it in your playbook directory, ansible will continue to use the _existing_ `atlas_user:`; for maximum clarity, the ideal outcome is to name the module `my_atlas_user:` to ensure (a) ansible and you are on the same page (b) it doesn't confuse future generations about why the `atlas_user:` task they might know now suddenly accepts new unknown parameters

Comment: @mdaniel - Thanks very much and the penny dropped when you mentioned renaming the module to something else.  I had my collection directory set up where the task was and when I renamed the module it couldn't find or recognise the renamed module. As it turns out I had installed the collection in the default /home/usr/.ansible/ directory previously, which is the default COLLECTION_PATH as per the ansible collections documentation. So turns out it was using that one instead. Every day is school day and I just needed a prod in the right direction. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing ansible galaxy collections, they are by default "installed" under your ~/.ansible/collections directory. Hence if making any changes to modules should ideally be made under that directory. I suggest the following read on installing collections

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/collections_using.html#installing-collections-with-ansible-galaxy